# How do I perform a sequence of actions with a single keybinding?

Tags: clojure, cider

i am using `cider`.  I want to do the following: when I finish editing in a source buffer, I want to compile the source and execute it in the repl, all with a single key-binding.

In `cider-mode`, compiling source can be done by `C-c C-k` or `M-x some-function`, so the workflow is basically like this: `C-c C-k`, `C-c C-z` (switch to repl buffer), and type and execute `my-function`.  How do I bind all the actions together and popup the repl buffer with results?

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this within a session is to record the actions as a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html), and then bind that macro to a key. You can also save the macro and binding to a file to use it across sessions. The details are provided in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the already defined shortcut?

```
C-c M-e
```

It evaluates the form preceding point and outputs to REPL buffer. See other [cider mode shortcuts here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: you see: maybe, i am editing namespace a.b, and will execute x.y/z in the repl, so it's not that easy by adding a.b/c in namespace a.b and `C-c M-e`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you, but did you look at other shortcuts that mode offers. It was developed by the people who developed cider, so I'm sure they have your case covered that I have missed.